# How to create one node in py2neo correctly?

Tags: py2neo

I just test py2neo demo,but failed,code is :

```
from py2neo.data import Node, Relationship
import py2neo
g = py2neo.Graph('http:/172.18.0.52:7474', user='neo4j',password='123')
a = Node("Person", name="Alice")
b = Node("Person", name="Bob")
ab = Relationship(a, "KNOWS", b)
print(a)
g.create(a)
```

output is : `(:Person {name: 'Alice'})`
traceback is :

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/internal/http.py
>   in fix_parameters(parameters)
>        70     try:
>   ---> 71         dehydrated, = dehydrator.dehydrate([parameters])
>        72     except TypeError as error:
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/internal/json.py
>   in dehydrate(self, values)
>       121 
>   --> 122         return tuple(map(dehydrate_, values))
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/internal/json.py
>   in dehydrate_(obj)
>       117             elif isinstance(obj, dict):
>   --> 118                 return {key: dehydrate_(value) for key, value in obj.items()}
>       119             else:
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/internal/json.py
>   in (.0)
>       117             elif isinstance(obj, dict):
>   --> 118                 return {key: dehydrate_(value) for key, value in obj.items()}
>       119             else:
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/internal/json.py
>   in dehydrate_(obj)
>       119             else:
>   --> 120                 raise TypeError(obj)
>       121
>
> TypeError:
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        10 
>        11 print(a)
>   ---> 12 g.create(a)
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/database.py
>   in create(self, subgraph)
>       343         """
>       344         with self.begin() as tx:
>   --> 345             tx.create(subgraph)
>       346 
>       347     def delete(self, subgraph):
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/database.py
>   in create(self, subgraph)
>       919             raise TypeError("No method defined to create object %r" % subgraph)
>       920         else:
>   --> 921             create(self)
>       922 
>       923     def delete(self, subgraph):
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/data.py in
>   **db_create**(self, tx)
>       612 
>       613     def **db_create**(self, tx):
>   --> 614         create_subgraph(tx, self)
>       615 
>       616     def **db_delete**(self, tx):
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/internal/operations.py
>   in create_subgraph(tx, subgraph)
>       133     for labels, nodes in _node_create_dict(n for n in subgraph.nodes if n.graph is None).items():
>       134         identities = _create_nodes(tx, labels, map(dict, nodes))
>   --> 135         for i, identity in enumerate(identities):
>       136             node = nodes[i]
>       137             node.graph = graph
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/internal/operations.py
>   in _create_nodes(tx, labels, data)
>        84     label_string = "".join(":" + cypher_escape(label) for label in sorted(labels))
>        85     cypher = "UNWIND $x AS data CREATE (_%s) SET _ = data RETURN id(_)" % label_string
>   ---> 86     for record in tx.run(cypher, x=data):
>        87         yield record[0]
>        88
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/database.py
>   in run(self, cypher, parameters, **kwparameters)
>       838         try:
>       839             if self.transaction:
>   --> 840                 result = self.transaction.run(cypher, parameters, **kwparameters)
>       841             else:
>       842                 result = self.session.run(cypher, parameters, **kwparameters)
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/neo4j/v1/api.py in
>   run(self, statement, parameters, **kwparameters)
>       603         if self.closed():
>       604             raise TransactionError("Transaction closed")
>   --> 605         return self.session.run(statement, parameters, **kwparameters)
>       606 
>       607     def sync(self):
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/internal/http.py
>   in run(self, statement, parameters, **kwparameters)
>       288         self._statements.append(OrderedDict([
>       289             ("statement", ustr(statement)),
>   --> 290             ("parameters", fix_parameters(dict(parameters or {}, **kwparameters))),
>       291             ("resultDataContents", ["REST"]),
>       292             ("includeStats", True),
>
> ~/miniconda2/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/py2neo/internal/http.py
>   in fix_parameters(parameters)
>        72     except TypeError as error:
>        73         value = error.args[0]
>   ---> 74         raise TypeError("Parameters of type {} are not supported".format(type(value).**name**))
>        75     else:
>        76         return dehydrated
>
> TypeError: Parameters of type map are not supported

the output is not correspond with the demo:'(alice:Person {name:"Alice"})'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe install the latest version (4.0.0) of py2neo. Some people met the same issue as you, his solution that you can follow [py2neo issue 678](https://github.com/technige/py2neo/issues/678).

Another solution is that you can install previous version, for example, `pip install py2neo==3.1.2`, it works for me.